# Mysql query for two tables

Tags: mysql

Consider I have 2 tables. `Items` and `bids`.

- `Items`:-- `id` (integer), `category` (integer).

`id` ranges from 1 to 8 and they are unique. In `Category`, it is 1 and 2 as example id: 1 to 4 is in category 1 and 5 to 8 is in category 2.

- `bids` table contains `item_id` which is similar to `Items.id`, which ranges from 1 to 8.

Now my query is, if I select a item from `bids.item_id`, I want to see what are id's in the same category.

As example: if I say in a query 
`WHERE item_id FROM bids is '2'`, I want to see other id's of same category that means it should return '1' '3' '4', since 1 to 4 items.id is in category=1

Comment: Can you format your question first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select i.* from
items i where i.category = 
(select i2.category from items i2 join bids b on b.item_id = i2.id and b.id = :INPUTBIDID)
```

this will find all items that share a category with the item from the bid you select. It does this with a subselect. So it does the select in the paranthesis (which finds the correct category) and it uses that in the where clause of the outer query.

Comment: Thanks! I will check and let you know. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need to reference the `bids` table at all, since `bids.item_id` is the same as `items.id`. You just want all items that are in the same category as some other item. You can do this with a simple self-JOIN.

```
SELECT i1.id
FROM items AS i1
JOIN items AS i2 ON i1.category = i2.category
WHERE i2.id = 2
```

If you actually have a `bid.id` and you want to find all the items in the same category as the item in the bid, you just add another join:

```
SELECT i1.id
FROM items AS i1
JOIN items AS i2 ON i1.category = i2.category
JOIN bids AS b ON b.item_id = i2.id
WHERE b.id = :bidID
```

Comment: Actually bids table has other information as well like, bids.user_id, bids.max_bid, bids.date etc. So when i select an item from bids.item_id i want to check what are the other id's in the same category!

Comment: The odds are also pretty high that the bids are what he has access to (since people are selecting a bid). In that case you would need a second join to the bids table (which is of course a viable solution), which complicates this a little.

Comment: I've added that version of the query

Comment: Perfect! it works! I have 1,88,227 items in bids. i have randomly chosen a single id (:bidID) to check, it worked! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are two possible solutions:

**1. your categories never change**

In your question, you mention that there are only 2 possible categories: 1 and 2, and they are fully dependent on the item id.
Will this always be like this? Then the answer is quite simple:

```
SELECT id FROM items WHERE items.category = {1 or 2 depending on which item was selected} AND items.id <> {id from selected item}
```

**2. your categories might change one day in the future**

```
SELECT id FROM items WHERE items.category = (SELECT items.category FROM items, bids WHERE items.id = bids.item_id)
```

Does this help?